# Как завершить команду end=

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, ввод, print

```
# Длинна окружности:

print("Введите радиус окружности в mm. :", end=" ")
r = int(input())
D = 2 * 3.141 * r

print("Длинна окружности:", end=" "); print(D, end=" mm.");
   
#S = π × r2 - площадь окружности
S = 3.141 * r ** 2

print("Площадь окружности:", end=" "); print(S, end=' mm.')
```

---

Вывод:

```
Введите радиус окружности в mm. : 11

Длинна окружности: 69.102 mm.Площадь окружности: 380.061 mm.
```

Comment: Не могу понять как сделать так, что бы строчка была

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```py
print(D, end=" mm.\n");
```

Comment: Спасибо, а я думал как ее эту N туда запихать)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что правильно понимаю вашу задачу, но попробуйте так:

```
print("Введите радиус окружности в mm. : ", end=" ")
r = int(input())
D = 2 * 3.141 * r
print(f"Длинна окружности:               {D:>8.3f}")

S = 3.141 * r ** 2
print(f"Площадь окружности:              {S:>8.3f}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: print("Длинна окружности:", end=" "); print(D, end=" mm.\n") Да нет, там надо было управляющий символ "\n" поставить, я просто не понял куда его втыкать.

Comment: Не че, научимся, 3 день только сижу) Пока интересно)

Comment: @АртемВалуев а для чего вам надо управляющий символ "\n" поставить? Вы его поставили и получили результат отличный от моего?

Comment: Что бы разделить строчку, как интером.

Comment: @АртемВалуев Вы его поставили и получили результат отличный от моего?

Comment: А я ваш и не использовал, я даже не понимаю что там написано

Comment: Я же говорю, я только 3 день сижу, читаю, пытаюсь сообразить, что да как.

Comment: @АртемВалуев удачи вам.

Comment: Будем учиться!...